# android TagHandler and CSS

Tags: android, html, css, textview

I'm trying to show HTML with TextView. My HTML contains some CSS styles. Here is an example of my HTML.

```
<p><strong>bold </strong><em>&nbsp;italic </em><span style="text-decoration: underline;">underlined</span>&nbsp;<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">striked</span><span style="font-family: symbol;"> custom font</span><span style="font-size: large;"> bigger&nbsp;</span></p>
<br/><p style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: x-small;">aligned to right</span></p>
<br/><p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: x-small;">aligned to center</span></p>
<br/><p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: x-small;">this text is justifyed&nbsp;</span></p>
<br/><p><span style="font-size: x-small; color: #ff0000;">colored&nbsp;</span></p>
<br/><p><span style="font-size: xx-large; color: #ff0000;"><span style="font-size: x-small;">symbol&nbsp;</span>&clubs;</span></p>
```

I can handle all tags with TagHandler. But I couldn't get any information about styles. Is it possible to get style information with TagHandler ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have already solved, but no. The `handleTag` method just gets the tag name into `String` format.